# c++ Problema al Dividir 2/3

Tags: c++, div, operadores

Necesito multiplicar un valor X por 2/3 (Dos Tercios), para lo cual estoy utilizando lo siguiente:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    double var;

    var=2/3;
    cout<<var<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

y para mi sorpresa obtuve **0** como salida. Pense que se debía a la cantidad de decimales por lo cual probé con lo siguiente

```
#include<iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    double var;
    cout.setf( ios::fixed );
    cout<<setprecision( 2 );

    var=2/3;
    cout<<var<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Pero de igual forma obtengo salida de 0.00
Estoy usando Code::Blocks 16.01, pero también lo probé en Dev-C++ 5.11 y obtuve la misma salida

Comment: El doble necesita que al menos uno de los operados sea doble. Prueba ```var=2.0/3```de lo contrario haces una división entera.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Es un *problema* muy divertido, te lo resumo con una analogía:

- Tienes una galleta.
- Tienes una caja de zapatos.
- Pones la galleta en la caja de zapatos.

¿Cuántos zapatos hay en la caja de zapatos?. Cero.

---

La analogía anterior no se ajusta del todo a esta situación pero sirve para ilustrar que estás trabajando con dos cosas distintas: enteros (`int`) y números en coma flotante de precisión doble (`double`).

#### [Literales](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal).

En C++<sup>1</sup> un conjunto de información que es interpretada por el compilador "tal y como está escrita" es un literal. En C++<sup>1</sup> existen varios tipos de literales:

- Numérico (entero y coma flotante).
- Carácter.
- Cadena.
- Booleano.
- Puntero nulo<sup>2</sup>.
- Definido por el usuario<sup>2</sup>.

#### Literales numéricos.

Los literales tienen un tipo subyacente, que varía según el prefijo o sufijo:

| Sufijo | Ejemplo | Tipo |
| --- | --- | --- |
|  | `1` | `int` |
| u | `2u` | `unsigned int` |
| l | `3l` | `long` |
| ll | `4ll` | `long long` |
| ull | `5ull` | `unsigned long long` |

Si el literal contiene un punto, se interpretará como un número en coma flotante:

| Sufijo | Ejemplo | Tipo |
| --- | --- | --- |
|  | `1.` | `double` |
| f | `.2f` | `float` |
| l | `3.l` | `long double` |

No es relevante para esta pregunta, pero los sufijos se pueden poner en mayúsculas o minúsculas y el literal se puede escribir en hexadecimal, octal o binario.

#### Operaciones matemáticas y promoción de tipos.

C++<sup>1</sup> no realiza operaciones con tipos distintos, antes de operar transforma los operandos a un tipo común siguiendo las normas del [estándar C++](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf) en el apartado §5.9.10 (la traducción y resaltado mío):

> Varios operadores binarios que esperan operadores de tipo aritmético o enumerado causan conversiones y devuelven tipos de una manera similar. **El propósito es devolver un tipo común, que es también el tipo del resultado**. Este patrón es llamado *conversiones aritméticas usuales*, que se define así:

> - ...
> - 10.2 Si alguno de los operandos es de tipo `long double`, el otro debe ser convertido a `long double`.
> - 10.3 En caso contrario, **si alguno de los operandos es `double`, el otro debe ser convertido a `double`**.
> - 10.4 En caso contrario, si alguno de los operandos es `float`, el otro debe ser convertido a `float`.
> - 10.5 En caso contrario las promociones integrales deben ser aplicadas a ambos operandos. Entonces las siguientes reglas serán aplicadas a los operandos promocionados:
> - **10.5.1 Si ambos operandos tienen el mismo tipo, no se requiere ninguna conversión adicional**.
> - 10.5.2 En caso contrario, si ambos operandos tienen tipos con signo o ambos tipos tienen tipos sin signo, el operando con el tipo con menor rango será convertido al tipo con mayor rango.
> - 10.5.3 En caso contrario, si el operando que tiene tipo entero sin signo tiene un rango mayor o igual al rango del tipo del otro operando, el operando con tipo entero con signo debe ser convertido al tipo del operando con tipo entero sin signo.
> - 10.5.4 En caso contrario, si el tipo del operando con tipo entero con signo puede representar todos los valores del tipo del operando entero sin signo, el poerando con tipo entero sin signo debe ser convertido al tipo con el operando con tipo entero con signo.
> - 10.5.5 En caso contrario, ambos operandos deben ser convertidos a tipo entero sin signo correspondiendo al tipo del operando entero sin signo.

En tu operación matemática de `2/3` vemos que usas dos literales numéricos, ambos literales son de tipo `int` (carecen de sufijo) así que el resultado de la operación será también de tipo `int`. La división entera de un número X por un número Y siendo Y > X es siempre `0` y ese es el resultado que se guarda en tu variable `var` de tipo `double`.
###Propuesta.
Si los operandos de tu operación son de tipo `double` el resultado será `double`:

```
var=2./3.;
```

Aunque con que uno de los operandos sea `double` sería suficiente:

```
var=2/3.;
```

---

<sup>1</sup>Y otros lenguajes.

<sup>2</sup>Exclusivo de C++.

Answer (score 4):

Tu problema es muy sencillo:

```
double var = 2 / 3;
```

Eso, desde el punto de vista del compilador, es equivalente a

```
double var = (int)2 / (int)3;
```

¿ Lo ves ya ? `var` es un `double`, pero los literales que estás usando, los *números*, **son enteros**.

Las acciones ocurren por separado: primero, se divide el entero 2 entre el entero 3; el resultado es otro entero, con valor `0`. **Después**, ese entero `0` se asigna a tu variable `double`.

Cambia tu código a

```
double var = 2.0 / 3.0;
```

Con eso, estás usando literales *double*, y el resultado es el esperado.

> 0.666667

Answer (score 0):

Como te han dicho la parte entera de 0.666667 (o 2/3) es 0. Los decimales se descartan ya que tú has definido la variable como entera. Si quieres que se tengan en cuenta los decimales tendrás que definirla de forma tal que acepte decimales (double, float...)

Comment: La única variable que hay definida en el código del autor es `double`.