# Imprimir decimales en c++

Tags: c++

La pregunta es básica.

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main()
{
    double resp = 0.8912637126836812;
    resp = 5/2;
    std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(4) << 5/2+20%6 << " || resp:" << resp;
    return 0;
}
```

Como salida obtengo.

```
4 || resp:2.0000
```

¿Por qué no me imprime en la primera operación el **4.5** y en la segunda el **2.5** que corresponde?

Si imprimo el valor original con el que inicialicé la variable, me la imprime sin problema.

¿Por qué?

Comment: Tema [relacionado](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/112440/2742).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> ¿Por qué no me imprime en la primera operación el 4.5 y en la segunda el 2.5 que corresponde?

Porque `setprecision` solo funciona con tipos decimales, es decir, con `float` y `double`.

En tu caso, todos los números involucrados en la operación son de tipo `int`, luego el resultado va a ser, sí o sí, de tipo `int` y, por tanto, no va a tener decimales.

Como te ha dicho [@GusZL](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/155477/463) la solución pasa por conseguir que el resultado sea decimal. Sin embargo, en C++ no soy partidario de usar una conversión *a pelo*. Esto no es C y en C++ hay 4 funciones especiales para realizar conversiones que son mucho más potentes y seguras que las usadas en C. Puedes obtener más información sobre el tema en esta otra [pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/6/cu%C3%A1ndo-usar-y-es-seguro-emplear-const-cast-static-cast-dynamic-cast-reinterp).

Para este caso valdría con `static_cast`:

```
static_cast<double>(5)/2+20%6
```

Fíjate que solo fuerzo la conversión de un número en vez del resultado de la operación... si hiciese esto:

```
static_cast<double>(5/2+20%6)
```

La operación `5/2` se realizaría sobre tipos enteros y devolvería `2` en vez de `2.5`. En cambio, en cuanto uno de los dos números es `double`, el compilador realizará una conversión de tipo `int` a `double` antes de ejecutar la operación:

```
numerador decimal:   5.0/2 => 5.0/2.0 = 2.5
denominador decimal: 5/2.0 => 5.0/2.0 = 2.5
ambos tipos enteros: 5/2   =  2             -> se descartan los decimales
```

Otra posibilidad es escribir los números que interesen directamente en notación decimal para que su tipo nativo sea `double`:

```
opción 1: 5.0/2
           ~~

opción 2: 5/2.0
             ~~

opción 3: 5.0/2.0
           ~~  ~~
```

Comment: +1 por `static_cast`.

Comment: Lo apliqué a otro problema y funcionó sin problemas.

Answer (score 3):

C++ no realiza operaciones con tipos distintos, antes de operar transforma los operandos a un tipo común siguiendo las normas del [estándar C++](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf) en el apartado §5.9.10 (la traducción y resaltado mío):

> Varios operadores binarios que esperan operadores de tipo aritmético o enumerado causan conversiones y devuelven tipos de una manera similar. **El propósito es devolver un tipo común, que es también el tipo del resultado**. Este patrón es llamado *conversiones aritméticas usuales*, que se define así:
>
> - ...
> - 10.2 Si alguno de los operandos es de tipo `long double`, el otro debe ser convertido a `long double`.
> - 10.3 En caso contrario, **si alguno de los operandos es `double`, el otro debe ser convertido a `double`**.
> - 10.4 En caso contrario, si alguno de los operandos es `float`, el otro debe ser convertido a `float`.
> - 10.5 En caso contrario las promociones integrales deben ser aplicadas a ambos operandos. Entonces las siguientes reglas serán aplicadas a los operandos promocionados:
>
>   - **10.5.1 Si ambos operandos tienen el mismo tipo, no se requiere ninguna conversión adicional**.
>   - 10.5.2 En caso contrario, si ambos operandos tienen tipos con signo o ambos tipos tienen tipos sin signo, el operando con el tipo con menor rango será convertido al tipo con mayor rango.
>   - 10.5.3 En caso contrario, si el operando que tiene tipo entero sin signo tiene un rango mayor o igual al rango del tipo del otro operando, el operando con tipo entero con signo debe ser convertido al tipo del operando con tipo entero sin signo.
>   - 10.5.4 En caso contrario, si el tipo del operando con tipo entero con signo puede representar todos los valores del tipo del operando entero sin signo, el poerando con tipo entero sin signo debe ser convertido al tipo con el operando con tipo entero con signo.
>   - 10.5.5 En caso contrario, ambos operandos deben ser convertidos a tipo entero sin signo correspondiendo al tipo del operando entero sin signo.

En todas tus operaciones estás usando literales son de tipo `int` así que el resultado de la operación será también de tipo `int`:

```
5/2 <-- 2 es int   5/2+20%6
^                  ^ ^ ^  ^
|                  | | |  |
\_ 5 es int        | | |  \_ 6 es int
                   | | \_ 20 es int
                   | \_ 2 es int
                   \_ 5 es int
```

> ¿Por qué no me imprime en la primera operación el **4.5** y en la segunda el **2.5** que corresponde?

Como ya hemos visto la operación `5/2` es de tipo `int`, por lo que realiza una división entera cuyo resultado es `2`, que al guardar en un `double` se queda en `2.0000`.

También hemos visto que la operación `5/2+20%6`, que por preferencia de operadores es equivalente a `(5 / 2) + (20 % 6)` es de tipo `int`, siendo `2` el primer resultado y `2` el segundo, por lo tanto la operación `2 + 2` también es de tipo entero y resulta en `4`.

#### Solución.

Como hemos visto en el apartado §5.9.10 del estándar, si al menos uno de los operandos es de tipo `double`, todos los operandos se transformarán automáticamente a `double` y la operación devolverá un `double`; lo más sencillo para esto es usar un literal `double` añadiendo un punto (`.`) al número:

```
int main()
{
    double resp = 0.8912637126836812;
    resp = 5./2.;
//          ~  ~ <-- ahora 5 y 2 son de tipo double
    std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(4) << 5./2.+20%6 << " || resp:" << resp;
//                   ahora 5 y 2 son de tipo double --> ~  ~
    return 0;
}
```

Este cambio provoca que toda la expresión sea de tipo `double` y resulta en:

> ```
> 4.5000 || resp:2.5000
> ```

Comment: Me gustó mucho tu solución, fue la que utilicé, aplica específicamente para el problema que plantee. Sin embargo si utilizo variables, agregar el punto no me serviría.

Answer (score 2):

Tienes que castear el resultado a **double**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main()
{
    double resp = 0.8912637126836812;
    resp = (double) 5/2;
    std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(4) << (double) 5/2+20%6 << " || resp:" << resp;
    return 0;
}
```

Hazme saber si te funciona

Answer (score 2):

Estoy de acuerdo con algunas de las respuestas (el resultado debe forzar el tipo a double), pero en mi humilde opinión la solución debe pasar por cambiar esto:

```
resp = 5/2;
```

por esto:

```
resp = 5.0 / 2.0;
```

o bien por esto:

```
resp = ((double) 5) / 2;
```

¿Porqué??? Pues porque en la solución anterior no queda claro si **primero** se está haciendo la conversión de 5 a double y **después** la división por 2 o bien es al revés: hacemos 5/2 como enteros (resultado 2, porque se trunca a entero) y luego convertimos ese 2 a double.

Los puristas dirán que mirando la precedencia de operadores queda el tema resuelto, pero creo que es mejor dejar a los lectores novatos la cosa clara.