# Como forzar a un número que imprima 1 decimal en C++?

Tags: c++, print

Quiero que al realizar cualquier operación la respuesta del número imprima un digito, así solo haya un 0.
Por ejemplo, supongamos que al sumar 0 y 0, me retorne 0.0
He tratado de utilizar la librería iomanip, pero sólo me retorna con un decimal cuando los números que ingreso tiene una o más cifras.

Hice éste código:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

class Suma{
  private:
    double numeroA, numeroB;
  public:
    Suma(double a, double b){
      numeroA = a;
      numeroB = b;
    }
    ~Suma(){}
    void realizarSuma(){
      cout<<setprecision(2)<<numeroA+numeroB;
    }
};

int main() {
  Suma numeros(0,0);
  Suma numeros2(2,1.141592);
  Suma numeros3(3,4);

  numeros.realizarSuma(); // Me retorna 0, y quiero que sea 0.0
  cout<<endl;
  numeros2.realizarSuma(); // Me retorna 3.1, pero es sólo porque el segundo número tiene decimales
  cout<<endl;
  numeros3.realizarSuma(); // Me retorna 7, y quiero que sea 7.0
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Duplicado de https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/155475/imprimir-decimales-en-c

Comment: Muchas gracias <3