# Asistencia con una código en cxxdroid

Tags: c++

Básicamente estoy intentando hacer un programa que calcule La velocidad con la fórmula velocidad es igual a distancia sobre tiempo pero el código que he escrito no parece estar funcionando, es el siguiente

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int Main ( )
{
    int dis, tie, vel;
    tie=42;
    dis=22;
    std::cout<< "Distancia"<<std::endl;
    cin>> dis;
    std::cout<< "Tiempo"<<std::endl;
    vel=dis/tie;
    std::cout<< "La velocidad es:" << vel;
}
```

Y me sale este error:

> :13:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
> }
> ^
> 1 warning generated.
> /data/user/0/ru.iiec.cxxdroid/files/bin/ld: /data/user/0/ru.iiec.cxxdroid/files/sysroot/usr/lib/crtbegin_dynamic.o:(.text+0x370): undefined reference to `main'
> clang-9: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: Bienvenido. ¿Qué quiere decir con que parece no funcionar? ¿Cuál es el resultado esperado y cuál es el obtenido? Mira cómo crear un [Example]

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [c++ Problema al Dividir 2/3](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/112394/c-problema-al-dividir-2-3)

Comment: Hola Bruh, aparte del ,problema de usar int para dividir, tu método carece de retorno y de eso se está quejando el sistema.

Comment: Si pones ```int main()``` estas indicando que ```main``` devuelve o retorna un entero, sin embargo, no estás retornando nada. Eso lo que te dice el mensaje. Por otro lado. Pides que te ingresen la distancia y luego parece que quieres que te ingresen el tiempo pero no hay un ```cin``` para el tiempo, por lo tanto, siempre vas a dividir cualquier distancia entre 42. Medio raro que pidas distancia pero no el tiempo. Supongo que te hace falta al final del main el ```return vel;```. Si no quieres retornar nada cambia el ```int``` por ```void```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes una alarma:

> warning: control reaches end of non-void function

Esta alarma indica que una función que debería haber devuelto un valor ha acabado sin devolver nada, en tu caso es la función `Main` en la que has definido `int` como tipo de retorno pero finalizas la función sin haber usado ningún `return`.

Por otro lado tienes un error de enlazado:

> undefined reference to `main'

Este error indica que el enlazador no pudo encontrar la función `main`. La función `main` es el punto de entrada de los programas [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), de no existir el programa "*no sabe*" por dónde empezar.

---

[c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) es un lenguaje que distingue entre mayúsculas y minúsculas, probablemente querías hacer esto:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
//  ^ <--- 'main', no 'Main'
{
    float dis, tie;
//  ~~~~~ <-- 'float' te permite hacer cálculos con decimales.

    cout << "Distancia\n";
    cin >> dis;

    cout << "Tiempo\n";
    cin >> tie;

    cout << "La velocidad es: " << (dis / tie) << "km/h";

    return 0; // Devolver valor ( https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/139716/2742 )
}
```